# Code coverage for ChartController

Tags: unit-test

I am trying to get code coverage for my requirement visualforce reporting. While trying to save test class it's throwing "compile error: Invalid type Data" please help me here what's wrong?. Anyway chartcontroller class is working fine and I am able run the class. Thanks in advance guys.

Chart controller class:

```
public class ChartController {
    // Return a list of data points for a chart
    public List<Data> getData() {
        return ChartController.getChartData();
    }    
    public static List<Data> getChartData() {
        List<Data> data = new List<Data>();        
        data.add(new Data('Feb', 2500));
        data.add(new Data('Mar', 13450));
        data.add(new Data('Apr', 13440));
        data.add(new Data('May', 19800));
        data.add(new Data('Jun', 15000));        
        return data;
    }    
    // Wrapper class
    public class Data {
        public String name { get; set; }
        public Integer data1 { get; set; }        
        public Data(String name, Integer data1) {
            this.name = name;
            this.data1 = data1;
        }
    }
}
```

And test class:

```
@isTest
private class ChartController_Test { 
 static testMethod void ChartTest(){
         List<Data> tstData = new List<Data>();
         tstData.Name = 'Test1';
         tstData.Data1 = '12121';                 
       insert tstData;               
        }        
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the method from the controller you created in your test class. You would need to do something like this.

```
@isTest
private class ChartController_Test{
static testMethod void ChartTest(){
ChartController controller = new ChartController();
controller.GetData();
}
}
```